# Time issue with left join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
select transcript_features.*,
    transcript_features_blast.hit, transcript_features_blast.evalue,
    transcript_features_blast.swissprot_version, 
    transcript_features_premirna_family.family, transcript_features_premirna_family.evalue,
    transcript_features_premirna_family.rfam_version, 
    transcript_features_premirna_homology.hit, transcript_features_premirna_homology.evalue,
    transcript_features_premirna_homology.mirbase_version,
    transcript_features_premirna.premirna, 
    transcript_features_transposons.hit, transcript_features_transposons.dfam_version, 
    confidence.confidence, expression.expression, expression.tissue, expression.conditions
from transcript_features_premirna, gene_transcripts, transcript_features_transposons, confidence, transcript_features
left join transcript_features_blast on transcript_features_blast.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join transcript_features_premirna_family on transcript_features_premirna_family.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join transcript_features_premirna_homology on transcript_features_premirna_homology.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join expression on expression.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
where transcript_features.transcript_alias=gene_transcripts.transcript_alias and gene_transcripts.gene_alias="AT1G19392" and transcript_features_premirna.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias and transcript_features_transposons.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias and confidence.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias;
```

This code works fine. Nevertheless, when I introduce an additional `left join`:

```
select transcript_features.*,
    transcript_features_blast.hit, transcript_features_blast.evalue,
    transcript_features_blast.swissprot_version, 
    transcript_features_premirna_family.family, transcript_features_premirna_family.evalue,
    transcript_features_premirna_family.rfam_version, 
    transcript_features_premirna_homology.hit, transcript_features_premirna_homology.evalue,
    transcript_features_premirna_homology.mirbase_version,
    transcript_features_premirna.premirna, 
    transcript_features_transposons.hit, transcript_features_transposons.dfam_version, 
    confidence.confidence, expression.expression, expression.tissue, expression.conditions
from transcript_features_premirna, gene_transcripts, transcript_features_transposons, confidence, transcript_features
left join transcript_features_blast on transcript_features_blast.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join transcript_features_premirna_family on transcript_features_premirna_family.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join transcript_features_premirna_homology on transcript_features_premirna_homology.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join expression on expression.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
left join transcript_names on transcript_names.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias
where transcript_features.transcript_alias=gene_transcripts.transcript_alias and gene_transcripts.gene_alias="AT1G19392" and transcript_features_premirna.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias and transcript_features_transposons.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias and confidence.transcript_alias=transcript_features.transcript_alias;
```

Takes an eternity, it does not finish, ever. Why? If I delete a random `left join`, it works nicely, and I get results in less than 0.30 seconds. Maybe, too many `left join`s?

The output of using `explain`:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                                 | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                         | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | confidence                            | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                        | 75858 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.confidence.transcript_alias          |     1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features_blast             | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.confidence.transcript_alias          |     1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features_premirna_family   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.confidence.transcript_alias          |     1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features_premirna_homology | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                        |  9530 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | expression                            | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                        | 75844 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_names                      | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.transcript_features.transcript_alias |     1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features_transposons       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.transcript_features.transcript_alias |     1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transcript_features_premirna          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.transcript_features.transcript_alias |     1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | gene_transcripts                      | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 42      | GreeNC.transcript_features.transcript_alias |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: use `explain` followed by the query in mysql and share the result to the question. This might answer why its slow.

Comment: Done. The output of `explain` in in my question.

Comment: you mean you cant use `explain` statement in mysql and it never finishes ?

Comment: Do not mix implicit (comma-) join syntax and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, do not us implicit syntax at all. Also, your result set must be confusing because so many column names are duplicated.

Comment: What do you mean regarding implicit/explicit?

Comment: ? I think I said already !?!

Comment: @user2979409 `from transcript_features_premirna, gene_transcripts, transcript_features_transposons, confidence, transcript_features`. All those are implicit joins. Most join conditions are hidden in your `where` clause.

Comment: @user2979409 please consider reading the [manual to joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html), I cite: _However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this section._

Comment: @VMai, what do you mean with "Most join conditions are hidden in your `where` clause"?

Comment: The condition `transcript_features.transcript_alias=gene_transcripts.transcript_alias` (first of your `WHERE` clause) should be used in `transcript_features INNER JOIN gene_transcripts ON transcript_features.transcript_alias=gene_transcripts.transcript_alias` and better rewritten with table alias names `transcript_features tf INNER JOIN gene_transcripts gt ON tf.transcript_alias = gt.transcript_alias` The other conditions of your WHERE clause apply to other INNER JOIN conditions too.

Answer (score 1):

A more proper way of writing this query might be as follows:

```
SELECT f.*
     , b.hit b_hit
     , b.evalue b_evalue
     , b.swissprot_version
     , pf.family
     , pf.evalue pf_evalue
     , pf.rfam_version
     , ph.hit ph_hit
     , ph.evalue ph_value
     , ph.mirbase_version
     , p.premirna
     , t.hit t_hit
     , t.dfam_version
     , c.confidence
     , e.expression
     , e.tissue
     , e.conditions
  FROM transcript_features f
  JOIN gene_transcripts gt
    ON gt.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias 
  JOIN transcript_features_premirna p
    ON p.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias 
  JOIN transcript_features_transposons t
    ON t.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias 
  JOIN confidence c
    ON c.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias
  LEFT 
  JOIN transcript_features_blast b
    ON b.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias
  LEFT
  JOIN transcript_features_premirna_family pf
    ON pf.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias
  LEFT
  JOIN transcript_features_premirna_homology ph 
    ON ph.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias
  LEFT
  JOIN expression e 
    ON e.transcript_alias = f.transcript_alias
 WHERE gt.gene_alias = "AT1G19392";
```

Comment: It's a good example (for me, opinion based :-)), that explit join syntax is more readable than implicit ones. And the mix of implicit ones with outer joins makes queries really tricky. It's easy to overlook (not here in this example) to overlook a condition that must go into the ON clause of an OUTER join.

Comment: you rewrote my first peace of code, which works fine. Could you rewrite my problematic block of code, the second piece?

Comment: Go on, have another go. And provide the EXPLAIN again (in case it's at all different)